# Rotate table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

Please help me a study case bellow:
I have a table in Postgres:

[image: Table A]

and how to create a view or Table B from Table A like this:

[image: Table B]

I try to use crosstab but it's not working.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMbf8.png)

Thank you so much!

Comment: You need to pivot the data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+and+([pivot]+or+[crosstab])+

Comment: What determines the order of the authors?

Comment: Thanks for your question, the order the authors is not important. may be the first is author_1, the second is author_2 ....

Comment: When there will be 10000 authors what the output you will expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would aggregate the authors into an array, then select the array elements in an outer query:

```
select item_id, 
       authors[1] as author_1,
       authors[2] as author_2,
       authors[3] as author_3
from (
  select item_id, 
         array_agg(author order by author) as authors
  from items
  group by item_id
) t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select item_id,
       max(author) filter (where seqnum = 1) as author_1,
       max(author) filter (where seqnum = 2) as author_2,
       max(author) filter (where seqnum = 3) as author_3,
       max(author) filter (where seqnum = 4) as author_4
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item_id order by author) as seqnum
      from tablea a
     ) a
group by item_id;
```